# Is there a way to use IIS to trigger a desktop application to open the GUI for the current user?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, iis, asp.net-web-api

**TL;DR**: Need to allow IIS (7-7.5) web service to open Internet Explorer with current user and have it visible. (Allow interaction with desktop)

Here's the problem and something I've tried:

I work at a university with monitors all throughout the school. Those monitors are just windows servers with a web browser open in kiosk mode.

The server that they interact with will fail from time to time and the web browsers (which refresh every 2 minutes) may be stuck in a bad state.

I have a way to monitor (using a 2nd server, nagios) when the page doesnt refresh properly and the simple solution would be to either refresh the browser or (simpler) open and close it again.

I need the remote server (nagios) to trigger the web browser to refresh via a Web Api call. I set up IIS on the server wrote a simple web service that's something like this:

```
closeAllProcessesWithNameIE();
Process.Start("Iexplorer", -k");
```

All instances of IE will close properly, and a process for IE will start up again (can see it in task manager). **HOWEVER** the GUI for IE will not show up.

Things I've tried (in all permutations):

1. make the application pool run as the current loggedin user.
2. trigger a secondary program to run IE, including a custom EXE, bat and Powershell script.
3. Enabled "Allow Service to Interact with Desktop" for the World Wide Web Publishing service.  (Remember IIS 7 does not have IISADMINSERVICE thats an IIS6 feature)
4. USER32.dll various functions to make the window appear ontop.

I'm considering writing a semaphore/lock file that is checked with task scheduler but this seems more hacky than the initial solution.

Things I am not worried about:

1. Remote code execution.
2. Hacking loggedin user account. (these accounts have no permissions whatsoever not even local admin)
3. someone constantly restarting the web browser (we're using a basic auth token over HTTPS)

Comment: The new process is probably starting under the IIS service account, not the interactive user account. Personally I'd write a little utility that runs on the user account that makes sure IE is running (check every X seconds) and if not, start it. The web api call can kill it, the utility can start it again under the right account.

Comment: IIS is actually running under the current loggedin use (the APP Pool is configured for that use) IE also opens AS THAT USER. The other idea though, that might be an easier way to implement a semaphore (lock file)  "IS IE running, NOPE! reopen it!

Comment: Just because the user is the same, doesn't mean its in an interactive session...

Comment: It's not. Is there anyway I can open a process in a different session?

Answer (score 0):

Using PsExec you can specify that you want the application you start to be attached to the current interactive session using the -i switch.

[PsExec download site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)